# Unchecked or unsafe operations without using annotation

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable, unsafe

I copied this piece of codes from a book I am currently reading...

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class DefaultComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> {
    public int compare(E a, E b) throws ClassCastException {
        return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

but it throws a compiler warning that it uses unchecked or unsafe operations. So how can I remove the warning without using the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: You would have either type-check `a` to be an `instanceof Comparable` or bound the generic type of `E` to `extends Comparable<E>`.

Comment: How can you guarantee `E` is `Comparable`?

Comment: @Turing85 can you please post the exact codes?

Comment: @robert Sure. My hourly wage is USD 200 before taxes.

Comment: Your generics are wrong as @Turing85 says. `E` is unbounded so it can be anything - your code will fail if `E` is not assignable to `Comparable`. I suggest deleting the code you have and simply using [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that E is extending the Comparable class:

```
public class DefaultComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<E> {
    public int compare(E a, E b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: And now you have just implemented `Comparator.naturalOrder()` - so maybe just use that instead.